# Set dropdownlist item text using server side method

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set the Text property of a drop down list option like this:

```
 <asp:ListItem Value="AB" Text='<%= Resources.Get("USA") %>'></asp:ListItem>
```

But it isn't working, instead the Text value is literally `<%= Resources.Get("USA") %>` and not the string "USA".

i.e. it is not being interpreted as code.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

use format `<%$ Resources: yourresoucefilename, stringname %>`

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that that syntax only works with sitmap files.

```
<%= ResourceFileName.ResourceVariableName %>
```

should work or
Setting the value in the code behind:

```
ListBox.Items.Add(ResourceFileName.ResourceVariableName);
```